# Bluemixの各サービスの障害情報等のステータスはどこで確認できますか？

Tags: bluemix

Bluemixには数多くのサービスが有りますが、障害の発生の有無をリアルタイムで確認出来るようなステータスページはありますでしょうか？ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

Bluemixの各サービスのステータスはデータセンターのロケーション毎に、下記で確認できます。

- 米国南部 (http://estado.ng.bluemix.net/)
- 英国 (http://estado.eu-gb.bluemix.net/)

また同様の内容を下記でも確認可能なようです。
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

また、IDSに関しては、下記でステータスを確認する事が可能です。
http://status.hub.jazz.net/